# xlsxwriter to http response (download file) but with user data (forms) in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, download, xlsxwriter

I'm stuck, I want to user on page create template to input data on based witch will be created a template. Here is what I got so far, but it wont work, I have tried with examples online, but those are usually don't take a data from users to create template.

This is `views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import workbook
from django.forms import Form, CharField, ChoiceField, IntegerField
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/home.html')

class TemplateForm(Form):
    doc_name = CharField(label='Document name')
    sheetnames = CharField(label='Sheetnames')
    choices = []
    for year in range (1900, 2050):
        choices.append( (year, year) )
    year1 = ChoiceField(label='Starting Year', initial=2021, choices=choices)
    year2 = ChoiceField(label='Ending Year', initial=2022, choices=choices)    
    row_names = CharField(label='Column names')

def create_template(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TemplateForm()
        return render(request, 'my_app/create_template.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = TemplateForm(request.POST)

def create_form(doc_name, sheetnames, years, row_names):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(doc_name + '_template.xlsx')
    worksheet_introduction = workbook.add_worksheet( "introduction" )
    for i in sheetnames:
        worksheet_data = workbook.add_worksheet(i)
        worksheet_data.write_row(0, 1, years)
        worksheet_data.write_column(1, 0, row_names)
    workbook.close()
    return workbook
```

This is `my_app/templates/my_app/create_template.html`

```
{% extends "my_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="create_template" method="GET">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h1>Create your template</h1>
  <div class="item">
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-block">
    <input type="button" type="submit" value="Create and Download!"/>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is `my_app/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='my-home'),
    path('create-template/', views.create_template, name='my-create-template'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the function create_template is duplicated?

```
`def create_template(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/create_template.html')`

`def create_template(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TemplateForm()
        return render(request, 'my_app/create_template.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = TemplateForm(request.POST)`
```

The first one does not contain TemplateForm(). It is always called with this:
path('create-template/', views.create_template, name='my-create-template')
. Try to remove the first one.

Comment: It is a same, worst part is because I don't get anything in terminal except that I'm in this page even now when I removed this part. I don't get where is a problem, why I don't get at least a something?

Comment: Did you include your `my_app/urls.py` in your `project/urls.py` ?